# Como setar o Background-image com SVG hospedado em outro local

Tags: html, css3, svg

Estou fazendo um site que necessita pegar um svg de um outro site ([www.teste.com.br/imagem.svg](http://www.teste.com.br/imagem.svg))
e seta-la como plano de fundo. Porém não estou conseguindo.

segue como estou fazendo:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height     attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
       <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="fullscreen">
            <iframe id="data"></iframe>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
           var div = document.getElementById('data');
           var data = new Date();

           var d = new Date();
           var mes = d.getMonth()+1;
           var dia = d.getDate();

           /// alterando o src
           var imagem = 'http://www.teste.com.br/clientes/svg/' + '01' + '/' + '01' + '.svg';
           div.style = 'background-image:url('+imagem+')';
       </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Poste seu `html` também.

Comment: segue meu html:)

Comment: Você quer setar o background da `div` ou do `iframe`?

Comment: De uma div.. coloquei errado vou editar hehehe

Answer (score 1):

Para isso você pode usar `div.style.backgroundImage='url('+imagem+')';`, remova também o

';' que vem depois da variável 'imagem' -> `background-image:url('+imagem;+')';`

```
var div = document.getElementById('data');
var data = new Date();

var d = new Date();
var mes = d.getMonth()+1;
var dia = d.getDate();

/// alterando o style
var imagem =         'http://www.teste.com.br/clientes/' + '01' + '/' + '01' + '.svg';
div.style.backgroundImage='url('+imagem+')';
```

Veja um exemplo:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puKR3/)

Comment: Não deu certo :/

Comment: Você testou se a imagem que esta tentando usar esta renderizando corretamente ? No exemplo online esta funcionando, veja: http://jsfiddle.net/puKR3/1/

Comment: Olha o meu source para vc ver http://www.karmo.com.br/clientes/arils/svg/01/01.svg não dá certo! :/

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você quer setar o `background` da `div` e não do `iframe` diretamente, pois sua variável de guarda o elemento se chama `div`. Se assim for você deve trocar sua selação para o seguinte:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
```

E seu html para:

```
<div id="fullscreen">
    <iframe id="data" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

E setar a image no background da div dessa maneira:

```js
var imagem = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg';
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+imagem+')';
```

Isso funcionou [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/95hQa/) para mim

Comment: Deu certo pra você?

Comment: @karmex, como o @Cahe disse em sua resposta parece que o problemas está nos cabeçalho da imagem `svg` que você está utilizando, tentou fazer os procedimentos que ele citou?

Comment: Sim tentei e não deu certo. :(

Answer (score 1):

Ao que parece não está funcionando porque o servidor remoto de onde você está tentando pegar a imagem está enviando o arquivo com cabeçalhos incorretos, isso faz com que o navegador ignore a imagem indevida.

Cabeçalhos:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Apr 2014 00:03:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 21:36:40 GMT
ETag: "29100b5-1f870-baf26a00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 129136
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Veja na última linha "Content-Type: text/xml".

**#edit**

Resposta daqui: http://kaioa.com/node/45

Crie um arquivo .htaccess no diretório onde ficam as imagens e coloque as seguintes linhas nele:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Comment: O que devo fazer? Pedir pro cliente trocar no server alguma coisa?

Comment: Editei com uma possível solução, veja se funciona para você.

Comment: Coloquei lá e não rolou :(

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) há dois problemas com os arquivos que seu servidor está enviando:

1. O `charset` do documento não está especificado;
2. O `Mime Type` está incorreto (ele está retornando `text/xml` em vez de `image/xml+svg`.

<sub>[Link direto pro resultado do teste](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.karmo.com.br/clientes/arils/svg/01/01.svg&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)</sub>

Não sei se *ambos* precisam ser corrigidos ou não, mas posso confirmar que o segundo é a causa raiz do seu problema. Fiz duas cópias do [arquivo mencionado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11197/como-setar-o-background-image-com-svg-hospedado-em-outro-local#comment19294_11198):

- [01.svg](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/01.svg) ([validação](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/01.svg&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) - passou)
- [01.xml](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/01.xml) ([validação](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/01.xml&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) - mesmo problema de `Mime Type`)

O Chrome abriu e exibiu ambos sem problema (em uma aba isolada), mas jogando ambos no jsFiddle [do Anderson B. Furlan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11198/215) o primeiro funcionou corretamente, mas o segundo não.

- [Exemplo correto](http://jsfiddle.net/puKR3/2/) (extensão `svg`)
- [Exemplo incorreto](http://jsfiddle.net/puKR3/3/) (extensão `xml`)

### Solução

O que você precisa fazer então é configurar o servidor para retornar o `Mime Type` correto. Se o web server é Apache - e [a solução do Cahe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11205/215) não funcionou pra você - então é necessário buscar um caminho alternativo. Não sei quais são as suas restrições (seu cliente está usando *shared hosting*? ou tem total controle do Apache? qual a plataforma?), mas deixo como exemplo a linha no meu `apache/conf/mime.types` que trata desse tipo:

```
image/svg+xml                   svg svgz
```

Esse arquivo está sendo incluído pelo `httpd.conf` da seguinte forma (comentários removidos por brevidade, exemplos de `AddType` mantidos):

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    ...
```

(Nota: não sei se faz diferença, mas aqui as extensões incluem o ponto, i.e. `.svg` em vez de `svg` - será que se você fizer isso no seu `.htaccess` resolve? Segundo [esse post](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/) o ponto deveria ser opcional...)

Seja como for que você tente resolver, use o [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) para verificar se as configurações aplicadas no servidor estão curtindo efeito.